# Create array or object with string key and send with post

Tags: javascript, php, arrays

I need something like below example, but in javascript, probably in an object or array:

Below is the php example with the indexes as strings(dynamically formed) and the values are userids:

```
$array = array(
'en_Us'=>array(5,8,9,5,888,654,etc),
'fr_FR'=>array(7,9,54,876,875,etc)
);
```

How to build something like this in javascript ?

I will send it via ajax post to a PHP file and need the array in above example as a result.

Comment: `var obj = {
  'en_Us':[5,8,9,5,888,654,etc],
  'fr_FR':[7,9,54,876,875,etc]
 };`

Comment: if you are generating that array dynamically using php then surely all you would need to do would be to echo the json_encoded value as a javascript variable?
var obj=<?php echo json_encode( $array );?>

Answer (score 0):

Your object should look like this :

```
var data = {
       'en_Us': [5, 8, 9, 5, 888, 654],
       'fr_FR': [7, 9, 54, 876, 875] 
};
```

once you get your data in php, you need to call the `json_decode` function

```
json_decode($data); // will return an object (stdClass)
json_decode($data, true); // will return an associative array
```